Why is the command `w` in Ubuntu 24.04 different than older versions
I tried running w (w - Show who is logged on and what they are doing.) in Ubuntu 24.04 and it output:
 08:11:52 up  5:23,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root              180.74.67.181    02:48    5:22m  0.00s  0.47s sshd: root@pts/0
root              180.74.67.181    04:01    5:22m  0.00s  0.01s sshd: root@pts/2

Those seems wrong, the IDLE time is wrong, the WHAT is wrong. How can I get the correct one in Ubuntu 24.04?
This is the result for Ubuntu 22.04.
 08:12:59 up 12 days,  3:22,  2 users,  load average: 0.49, 0.67, 0.70
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0    180.74.67.181    03:17    0.00s  0.04s  0.00s w
root     pts/1    180.74.67.181    04:06    4:05m  0.03s  0.03s -bash


Bump this. I just upgraded to 24.04 and ran into the same issue.

me too, I think something got broken and no regression caught it

who -u -H comes close to covering what's missing from w

another option is to copy w from a 22.04 installation :-) you also need  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprocps.so.8 but with those two the old version yields the correct/previous version information

I've filed a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps/+bug/2092307
